# change user picture size n wordpress get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('user_email'), 75)

Tags: wordpress

I have site http://insideoutdogtraining.com/young-calicoe-dog-fighting where author box is coming under post content using plugin http://dempseymarketing.com/products/relauthor-plugin-for-wordpress/.

But i want to increase the size of author image so it will fit to main author box div. but i change any other value in get_avatar that is of no use, it is shoing 50x50 only. 
how i increase the size of image ?

Answer (score 1):

If your themes support custom css, try add this css to make it's looks prettier:

```
.author-title {margin-top: 0;}
.data-image .avatar {border-radius: 6px; width: 80px; height: 80px;}
.author-box {width: 100%; padding: 0 30px 20px 0; clear: both;}
```

You will get result like this: http://prntscr.com/6aenaz

Answer (score 0):

Why not just using this lines of code in your theme instead of plugin?

```
<?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) && ( ! function_exists(  'is_multi_author' ) || is_multi_author() ) ) : // If a user has filled out their  description and this is a multi-author blog, show a bio on their entries ?>
        <div id="author-info">
            <div id="author-avatar">
                <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), apply_filters( 'yourthemesname_author_bio_avatar_size', 68 ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- #author-avatar -->
            <div id="author-description">
                <h2><?php printf( __( 'About %s', 'yourthemesname' ), get_the_author() ); ?></h2>
                <?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?>
            <div id="author-link">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" rel="author">
                    <?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'yourthemesname' ), get_the_author() ); ?>
                </a>
            </div><!-- #author-link -->
        </div><!-- #author-description -->
    </div><!-- #author-info -->
<?php endif; ?>
```